# setText to TextView in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I just want to setText to text TextView after I get the content of given url what am I doing wrong ?

I have created class which should just setText to defined textview but there seems to be a problem somewhere as I get only blank textView on running the app. The code for the async task:

```
private class RetriveSiteData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String pom = "";

        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    pom += s + "\n";
                    //publishProgress(pom);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return pom;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        text.setText(s);
    }

    protected void onProggresUpdate(String s) {
        text.setText(s);
    }

}
```

and the main class definition looks like :

```
public class Today extends Fragment {

TextView text;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View today = inflater.inflate(R.layout.today, container, false);
    text = (TextView) today.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // ((TextView) today.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Today");

    new RetriveSiteData().execute("http://menza.lupajz.eu/?den=dnes");

    return today;
}
```

That on progressUpdate was just a test :/ no idea what is wrong.

Solved ! forgot to update manifest !

Comment: onProgressUpdate is spelled wrong and does not override the parent function. Have you checked that you are actually getting a proper response from the server?

Comment: can you log the value of `pom`?

Comment: there is only 1 url. why is for loop required?. you can directly use `urls[0]`.

Comment: What if he someday wants to use multiple URLs?

Comment: @NathanWalters use a executor for parallel execution

Comment: @Nathan Walters updated the onProgressUpdate method, added notation but still nothing

Comment: @XOOLOOO log the response. Remove for loop

Comment: I think it would help if you put in some `Log` messages, specifically inside your while loop to make sure the content was retrieved successfully, as well as right above `return pom;` to make sure that your `pom` value looks correct.

Comment: Verify that doInBackground is returning a non-empty String.            text.setText("VALUE: [" + s + "]");

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/r0PTORX.jpg there are some W errors :P no idea

Comment: My bad ! forgot to update android manifest ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the textView as a parameter on your asynckTask constructor.

```
new RetrieveSiteData(mTextView);
```

Then your can setText as you wish, but only in your onPostExecute method.

Comment: no i don't think so. Asynctask is probably an inner class in this case

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is wrong parameter in `onProgressUpdate()`
You should pass `Array` as the parameter of that method.
Try to replace:

```
@Override
    protected void onProggresUpdate(String s) {
        text.setText(s);
    }
```

To:

```
@Override
    protected void onProggresUpdate(String... progress) {
        text.setText(progress[0]);
    }
```

If you don't want to publish progress. just try `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`
and delete your `onProgressUpdate()` method.

Comment: fixed that sooner, that was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start your `AsyncTask` inside `onAttach`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
   super.onAttach(activity);
   new RetriveSiteData().execute("http://menza.lupajz.eu/?den=dnes");
}
```

onPostExecute is probably getting called before view is actually displayed so try to start your async task in onAttach and check.